# AWS Lambda connects with RDS using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-data-jpa, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS Lambda, We have an already developed application which relies on Spring Data JPA for data access layer. Now in progress of separating individual modules as separate microservices. We are moving on to AWS Lambda. I'm able to see many examples which show how to connect to RDBMS using simple JDBC connection.

How to use Spring Data JPA in AWS Lambda for data access layer?.

Answer (score 0):

Its the same way you would on your traditional servers or container instances (essentially thats all AWS Lambda is a short lived container).

```
    System.out.println("Connecting to database...");

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://master.zxxsecygfasd.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/";
    String database = "db_name";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "somepass";

    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + database, userName, password)) {

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Database connection: Failed");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

There are however some caveats this will be only able to hit a publicly accessible database from lambda. If you put your Lambda in a specific VPC you are going to need to configure roles for it, security groups and access control.

And finally on the note of JPA there are examples floating out there (Its also pretty standard). I have used hibernate before my personal opinion is that it was a bit heavy.